# C# class that would represent JSON data

Tags: c#, json, json.net

what would the C# class definition look like to represent this JSON data?

```
{
        "accountId": "101",
        "website": "www.example.com",
        "alternateWebsites": [
          {
            "website": "site2.example.com"
          }
        ],
        "email": "contact@mysite.com",
        "alternateEmails": [
          {
            "email": "sales@example.com"
          }
        ],
        "address": {
           "street": "234 Main Street",
           "city": "San Diego",
           "postalCode": "92101",
           "state": "CA"
         },
        "rankingKeywords": 
         [{
            "keyword": "Coffee",
            "localArea": "Sacramento, CA"
          }]
}
```

Comment: VS will do this for you.  Copy JSON to clipboard. **Edit menu -> Paste Special - -> Paste JSON as Classes**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a site like this http://jsonutils.com/

where you paste in your json and it constructs your classes for you. The result of your JSON produced...

```
public class AlternateWebsite
{
    public string website { get; set; }
}

public class AlternateEmail
{
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

public class RankingKeyword
{
    public string keyword { get; set; }
    public string localArea { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public IList<AlternateWebsite> alternateWebsites { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public IList<AlternateEmail> alternateEmails { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public IList<RankingKeyword> rankingKeywords { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could convert this with a service like http://json2csharp.com/. Enter the JSON and it will spit out C# model classes. Then, add them either as a class, or using Entity Framework (depending on your objective) into your project.

C# version:

```
public class AlternateWebsite
    {
        public string website { get; set; }
    }

public class AlternateEmail
{
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

public class RankingKeyword
{
    public string keyword { get; set; }
    public string localArea { get; set; }
}



public class RootObject
{
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public List<AlternateWebsite> alternateWebsites { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public List<AlternateEmail> alternateEmails { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public List<RankingKeyword> rankingKeywords { get; set; }
}
```